# Django admin list view prevent choices lookup

Tags: python, django

```py
class CustomerChoices(object):
    def expensive_lookup(self):
        ....

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from [(a.number, a.display) for a in self.expensive_lookup()]


class CustomerProfile(models.Model):
    account_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, choices=CustomerChoices())
    ...
```

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import CustomerProfile


@admin.register(CustomerProfile)
class CustomerProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('account_number', ...)
```

Given above code, while I am happy with the add/edit admin to use the choices, how do I prevent django admin list view using the choices, so it doesn't make an expensive lookup? Please note that I am aware of caching methods, but what if I just want to display the account number?

Comment: list view only render the data from the database, afaik, Django doesn't call the choice options during the AdminListView, does it?

Comment: Apparently it does use the choices to render the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue

When you put ***`list_display = ('account_number', ...)`*** in the model admin, Django fetching the ***"display value"*** by ***evaluating*** the choice iterable, and note that this ***"display value"*** doesn't belong to the database and hence the choice evaluation is a must-do thing.

#### Solutions

You have two choices,

1. Display the ***stored value*** from the database
2. Keep things the same as before

For the first solution, you can define *custom callable list methods* as

```
@admin.register(CustomerProfile)
class CustomerProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('account_number_dup',)

    def account_number_dup(self, model_instance: CustomerProfile):
        return model_instance.account_number
```

Answer (score 0):

JPG's answer seems OK for text or numbers.

But for booleans the value shown as result are `True` and `False` instead of images usually shown by Django.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30782913)